# in the link below, why did they add "-1" at slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block" in javascript step?

Tags: javascript

in the link below,  why did they add "-1" at slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block" in javascript step?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: This is to funnel through the contents of an array

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that it is because the value of slideIndex (1) is compared with the length of slides and because the value of slideIndex is increased by 1 then subtracts it to avoid the `undefined` when trying to access an element of the slide array out of range.

For example

Having an array with the following values, and remember array are 0 indexes

```
const slides = [1, 2, 3];
```

And if you try to access the position 4

```
slides[4];
```

You will get an `undefined` and in the context of slideshow you will probably get an error, so in order to prevent this error you substrcat slideIndex value before get a value in slide array.

It is usually more common to subtract at length 1 and start index counting at 0.

Comment: what about for this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

they still used the slides[slideIndex-1] @Mario